# What is the quickest way to install Oracle Java6 or Java7 on any Ubuntu?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Oracle Java JRE 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7)

There are tons of complicated answers on askubuntu on how to install any version of Java. Is there a quick and easy way to install the official Oracle packages on Ubuntu?